# Can I open an editor as part of a piping command to edit the piped string?

Tags: bash, pipe, nano

I would like to do this:

```
git --git-dir=../navcl/.git format-patch -k -1 --stdout 607780ee9 \
  | nano \
  | git am -3 -k
```

The issue is, in my other git dir, a file path is different, so I need to edit this in the patch. I could go via a file, but is there the option to edit the piping command in an editor? My use of `nano` here doesn't actually work, since I'm not aware how to get it to write to stdout.

Comment: If only there was a streaming editor >.>.  If you can show us an example of the string(s) you would like to edit, including sample input and expected output, I'm sure someone can help you with `sed`.

Comment: My question is specifically about interactively editing a string using vim, nano or similar. Although in principle I could craft a `sed` replacement, of course. (It would be error-prone, though, because even if I edit the path I need to adapt, I cannot generally be sure that this path does not appear as part of the patch contents, where it might not need to be changed.)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid using the POSIX standardized, and mostly universally available and extremely portable tool that was specifically created to solve the problem you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot generally be sure that this path does not appear as part of the patch contents".  If you provide some examples I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: I can't share the actual patch with you, but I assume you're familiar with the git patch format? I need to change a path as it is interpreted by the patch parser; while leaving any string that is not interpreted by git's parser intact. In the general case, this might mean emulating a portion of the parser functionality in sed. (In particular, think about what happens when I check in a git patch into git, and patch the patch.) Not feasible.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it, but as `sed` is turing complete, pretty much anything that is possible is possible in `sed`.  Since so far everything about your task seems to be describing the standard use of `sed`, I'm sure it will be a relatively easy command to come up with.

Comment: I didn't say impossible, I said infeasible :D some things are just very easily identified by the human eye, while being very hard to derive a complete specification for.

Comment: @FelixDombek: You still haven't showed us what you are trying to do so I can't say, however I can pretty much guarantee you it isn't nearly as hard as you think it is.

Comment: @muru `vipe` is a great suggestion, thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: @Jesse_b I'm trying to learn something here. Yes, for my specific case I already came up with a sed command. But it's not reusable for more complicated cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what the back and forth is helping.  We are here:  You are trying to convince me your problem is more complicated than I think it is, but wont show me your problem.  I don't believe your problem is as complicated as you think it is, and I **will not** believe it until you show me your problem.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing a script or function which saves the input to a temporary file, edits it, and then writes it out. Something like this: `pipevi(){ t=$(mktemp) && cat >"$t" && vi "$t" </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1 && cat "$t" && rm "$t"; }`.